# Google Sitemap Generator error 'is not a supported Apache binary or control script' during installation

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, xml-sitemap

I have a LAMP configurated server AMD64 with Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache2 on an EC2 instance.

I followed the [official guide here](http://googlesitemapgenerator.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/gsg-installation.html#gsg_i_lin), so first

I downloaded the `sitemap_linux-x86_64-beta1-20091231.tar.gz` and unpacked it

Then I typed `sudo sitemap-install/install.sh –-apache-bin=/usr/sbin/apache2` and here comes my problem:

```
What is the location of the Apache binary or control script?
[/usr/sbin/apache2] should support -V option.
/usr/sbin/apache2 is not a supported Apache binary or control script.
```

I'm sure about the location, infact if I restart Apache from the log file I can see `AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'`. I have also tried using this as location `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl` but no way.

I tried searching on Google for days without find anything.

Why I cannot install the Google Sitemap Generator using `/usr/sbin/apache2` as location of my Apache?

**UPDATE**

if I type `apache2 -V` the output is a list of warning `Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}` but it's because the request output from the `/usr/sbin/apache2` binary directly and so the `/etc/apache2/envvars` file isn’t sourced as explained [here](http://www.howdididothat.info/2014/10/07/invalid-mutex-directory-in-argument-file/)

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't the documentation say to use `-a` and not `--apache-bin`, so you should be doing:

```
sudo sitemap-install/install.sh –a /usr/sbin/apache2
```

Both my `apache2` binary and my `apache2ctl` control script understand the `-V` argument:

```
root@:~# apache2 -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 24 2015 17:25:42

root@:~# apache2ctl -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 24 2015 17:25:42
```

Comment: I tried your solution, same error `[/usr/sbin/apache2] should support -V option.`

Comment: if I type `apache2 -V` the output is a list of warning `Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}` but it's because the request output from the `/usr/sbin/apache2` binary directly and so the `/etc/apache2/envvars` file isn’t sourced as explained [here](http://www.howdididothat.info/2014/10/07/invalid-mutex-directory-in-argument-file/)

Comment: You're not typing those square brackets `[` and `]` in anywhere, right? Just making sure... :-)

Comment: that is the error message, no I'm not typing square brackets

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you should be doing this:

sudo sitemap-install/install.sh –-apache-bin=/usr/sbin/apachectl

Also the /usr/sbin/apachectl is likely a soft link so just run an `ls -la` on that if you want to know the real location.

Comment: `apachectl -> apache2ctl` located in the same folder, but also using this `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl` I get the same problem `[/usr/sbin/apache2ctl] doesn't point to a supported Apache instance.
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl is not a supported Apache binary or control script.`

Comment: Then that cannot be how you are restarting Apache.

Comment: `sudo service apache2 restart` then I tried again the installation and same problem...from the `error.log` Apache has started `AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'` so the location is correct, then why I cannot use `/usr/sbin/apache2` for install this sitemap generator?

Comment: Well if you are using service to start it then apache2 should be in /etc/init.d or perhaps /etc/init depending on which flavour of Linux you're running. A quick Google gives this which should set you on your way: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples

Comment: I don't have any problem with my server, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 as OS, but again my Apache and all my server are configured perfectly

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear. That link, if you scroll down, explains how the "system" command works and what executable it actually calls. Which might help you figure out how your Apache runs, which should help with your problem.

Comment: Apache already runs without problems, and I already have the necessary knowledge for those commands. It's something else

Comment: Well it seems to me from above that you don't know which command to use to start Apache outside of the "system" way of starting it and that is the core of the problem? Or am I misunderstanding.

Comment: Could be related to my EC2 instance instead?